# Interfacing FPGA to an external chip and timing constraints

Tags: fpga, design, xdc

I have designed a system using Artix-7 FPGA on a custom board. The goal is to transfer 32-bit data to an external onboard chip whose data bus is an `inout` port. First, a little background:

The external chip is driven by a 100MHz clock which is generated by the FPGA, let's call it `o_clk`. The FPGA generates this clock through an MMCM in the Memory Interface Generator (MIG IP) using the 200MHz differential system clock. The `o_clk` is looped back from the FPGA's output and is given to another ball as an input clock, let's call it `i_clk`.

The external chip receives the `o_clk` and sees data on this clock's rising edge. However, when the external chip sends data back to FPGA, the FPGA sees this data on the looped back `i_clk`. The idea behind doing so is that we can treat communications as source synchronous, in both the directions (remember, it is an `inout` port). Something like below:

```
FPGA --> EC is synchronous to FPGA because FPGA generates a clock
EC   --> FPGA is synchronous to EC because FPGA gets an external clock (virtually from EC)
```

To constrain this design, I have used the `i_clk` to set input delays on the `io_data` and have used the `o_clk` to constrain output on the same `io_data` bus. I have made sure I am using a forwarded clock (`create_generated_clock`)(using the ODDR2) for the `set_output_delay` constraint.

Here are my constraints:

```
create_clock -period 10.000 -name i_clk -waveform {0.000 5.000} [get_ports i_clk]
set_clock_groups -name loopback_grp -asynchronous -group [get_clocks i_clk] -group [get_clocks o_clk]

set_input_delay -clock i_fx3_pclk -max 8.000 [get_ports io_fx3_fdata]
set_input_delay -clock i_clk -min 2.000 [get_ports io_data]

set_output_delay -clock o_clk -max 2.000 [get_ports io_data]
set_output_delay -clock o_clk -min -0.500 [get_ports io_data]
```

The system seems to work properly when I run it on hardware, but I still have some doubts because I am still an amateur FPGA developer and this is my first big FPGA design.

My questions are:

1. Have I designed a good system?
2. Is it correct to treat the communication from EC --> FPGA as source synchronous? (The other direction is source sync because FPGA is providing clock if I am not wrong.!)
3. Are my constraints correct?

Comment: By these constraints, `i_clk` is asynchronous to `o_clk`. Did you intend this? If you want to make them synchronous, you must define them in the same clock group. For example, `-group [get_clocks "i_clk o_clk"]`.

Comment: If you know the clock/data trace distances between the FPGA and the external device, you should be able to treat the system as a system-synchronous interface. That is, the data returned will have a predictable timing pattern relative to o_clk. In that case, there would be no reason to use i_clk, just constrain relative input data relative to o_clk and clock in with o_clk, and maybe use IDELAYs to meet timing. If the trace length is unknown (the clock/data travel through a cable length that is not known at design time), you will have to treat i_clk as asynchronous.

Comment: @ahmedus, yes, I did that on purpose, because the `i_clk` is looped back in hardware and it doesn't know that both the clocks are related. Should I make them synchronous in a design point of view.?

Comment: The cases are well explained in @user2913869's comment. Shortly it depends on whether the external delay is known.

Comment: Do you have more information about your target device? Some devices natively support source-synchronous operation. Also, you will definitely want to set the clocks as related because they obviously have no frequency error between them.

Comment: Looping the clock back on the board doesn't accomplish much if it's just a ball to ball connection. Ideally you would serpentine the trace back to i_clk so that it's length is 2x the length of the data traces to the other chip. This mimics the delay of the clock/data to the other chip and the delay of the data back to the FPGA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you're trying to do is create a delayed clock to capture your input, and thus allow more setup time for the return signals. While treating the return signals as 'source sync' with a clock that flies with them seems logical, it's not so well controlled: the return clock signal integrity adds another variable to your timing.

You could instead use a phase-shifted clock that captures your input. This is much better controlled and totally dealt with inside the FPGA.

A safe amount of phase shift is at least the output hold time of your far-end device, plus your best-case (fastest) calculated round-trip flight time, entered as your set_output_delay -min value (entered as a negative number for hold time.)